# Dilation (imdilate) does not "thicken" or shape change as it is supposed to

Tags: matlab, image-processing

The book states that in image processing dilation is used to "thicken" objects in a binary image. Furthermore the author used `imdilate` in an example to fix or thicken broken text from a scanned document. `imdilate` kind of filled the gaps and cracks in the poorly scanned text document.

So in a way in dilation the new image formed takes the shape of the structuring element or in other words even if one pixel of the structuring element overlaps with the object in the image, the object's pixels are extended in the direction of the structuring element.

So in order to test this myself I wrote simple code to see how this works. I used it on this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Xd6.jpg

Here is the code I wrote:

```
logical = imread('edifice.jpg'); 

line = strel('line', 30, 45);
square = strel('square', 30);

%dilate logical with line @ 45 degrees

dial_logical_line = imdilate(logical, line);
figure, imshow(dial_logical_line), title('dial logical line');

%dilate logical with square.

dial_logical_square = imdilate(logical, square);
figure, imshow(dial_logical_square), title('dial logical square');
```

Dilation with line structuring element produced this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnov4.jpg

And dilation with square structuring element produced this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VguW0.jpg

Now based on the definition I understood above I was expecting different results. In case of line I was expecting the watch to be kind of smeared at 45 degree angle and in case of the square structuring element I was expecting a black square.

It is safe to say that I do not understand the result I got based on what I understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`imdilate` enhances the bright region, so if you are expecting a black square in your second case, you would try `imerode`:

```
file='http://imgur.com/ka2wLqK.jpg';
logical = rgb2gray(imread(file)); 
square = strel('square', 30);
dial_logical_square = imerode(logical, square);
figure, imshow(dial_logical_square), title('dial logical square');
```

The bright regions are eliminated and black regions are expanding:

[image]

Regarding your first case, I am still trying to understand what result are you expecting? It looks good that `imdilate` thicken all the bright regions along 45 degree for you. In fact, the `imerode` and `imdilate` are often combined to achieve some effects. You can keep the lines along 45 degrees and thick enough bright, and eliminate others (turn to black), by eroding (remove small bright lines) then dilating (enhancing the thick bright lines) the image. `imopen` performs this for you:

```
file='http://imgur.com/ka2wLqK.jpg';
logical = rgb2gray(imread(file)); 
imshow(logical)
line = strel('line', 10, 45);
dial_logical_line = imopen(logical, line);
figure, imshow(dial_logical_line), title('dial logical line');
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That looks fine to me. Remember in a binary image the pixels of interest are the 1-valued, or white ones. You can see each (white) pixel in the original image has been "smeared" into a 45-degree line and square respectively - if you invert the image first, you'll see what happens to the watch itself, rather than the background ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can try [Morphological Operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) (MO) in the binary image. MOs preserve the small lines and work as filters and remove noises from the image. you can combine a sequence of MOs to get the best results and iterated n or Inf times. I executed the code here using bwmorph in Matlab;

```
I = imread('clock1.jpg');
logical= rgb2gray(I);
imshow(logical);
L2 = imbinarize(logical);
I2 = bwmorph(L2,'majority',4);
I3 = bwmorph(L2,'spur',2);
I4 = bwmorph(I3,'fill',2);
I5 = bwmorph(I4,'clean',1);
figure, imshow(I5),title('Morphological operations');>
```

The output image looks like:

[image]